# Google Python script in Windows Executable format

Tags: python, google-bigquery, py2exe

I have a Python script that connects to google bigquery Project and creates an aggregate. Python as .py file is running fine after google bigquery authentication. When I changed Python file to Windows Executable (.EXE), my python script is not working. I did google authentication on windows machine still gives an error: type 'exceptions.IOError

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by `When I changed Python file to Windows Executable (.EXE)`? How did you change it to that?

Comment: check the steps here:http://www.logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script

Comment: You should write that you used py2exe to convert